# C# Get exception property

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, properties, inspector

How can I get the **FileRowNumber** from exception?

[Visual studio inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmsZs.png)

Code below:

```
    try
    {
        using (GenericParserAdapter parser = new GenericParserAdapter(dataSource, Encoding.Default))
        {
            parser.ColumnDelimiter = delimiter;
            parser.FirstRowHasHeader = FirstRowHasHeader;
            parser.FirstRowSetsExpectedColumnCount = true;
            parser.TrimResults = true;
            return parser.GetDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("exceeds ExpectedColumnCount"))
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to catch the specific exception type in order to access its type-specific properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific with the type of your exception: instead of using the generic **Exception** type, you need to use the **ParsingException** type provided from the library **GenericParsing** that you're using:

```
    try
    {
        using (GenericParserAdapter parser = new GenericParserAdapter(dataSource, Encoding.Default))
        {
            parser.ColumnDelimiter = delimiter;
            parser.FirstRowHasHeader = FirstRowHasHeader;
            parser.FirstRowSetsExpectedColumnCount = true;
            parser.TrimResults = true;
            return parser.GetDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (ParsingException e)
    {
        if (e.Message.Contains("exceeds ExpectedColumnCount"))
        {
            int fileRowNumber = e.FileRowNumber;
        }
    }
```

Now you're wondering "where can I found this information?" well, it's right there in the screenshot you posted (underlined it in green for you)

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I had no idea there was a "ParsingException"